# Django - How to specify different `Default Form Widget` for Bleach for different BleachFields?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Suppose this is a model for blog:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = BleachField()
```

And this is another model:

```
class Status(models.Model):
    content = BleachField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

How to override the BleachField to use different WYSIWYG editor for different Textarea widget? i.e., for `Status` their will be a different editor and for `Blog` their will another. Or is it OK to use use different WYSIWYG editor in the first place and then in the templates, use the bleach filter as:

```
{% load bleach_tags %}

{{ some_unsafe_content|bleach }
```

Any help will be much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just override `__init__` method while defining model form?:

```
class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BlogForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['content'].widget = forms.Textarea
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue.

At first I struggled with creating a custom char field, but then realized I could just do this, works pretty well:

```
class BlondeCharField(models.CharField, BleachField):
   pass
```

BleachField only needs to override `pre_save` ...